# Proper manipulation of file name string in C

Tags: c, string, file-io

I'm writing a program to convert one specific file format let's say `file.foo -> file.bar`. It's the first time I'm using C for file I/O (I've always used php in the past). I would like an opinion about the first part of the program: create the output file name from `argv[1]`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    
    if(argc == 1) {
        printf("Need a .foo file");
        return 0;
    }

    char *ext = strrchr(argv[1], '.');
    if(!ext || strcmp(ext, ".foo")) {
        printf("Not a .foo file");
        return 0;
    }

    char *basename = (strrchr(argv[1], '\\'));
    if(!basename) {
        basename = argv[1];
    } else {
        basename++;
    }

    char *out_name = (char*) malloc((strlen(basename)+1)*sizeof(char));
    sprintf(out_name, "%.*s.bar", (int) (ext - basename), basename);
    
    /* CODE */
}
```

My concerns are:

- preserving `argv[1]`
- work with absolute and relative path (`C:\User\path\file.foo`, `.\file.foo`, `file.foo`)

It works fine (from what I can tell). Have I missed something or perhaps have I used redundant variables? I'm asking purely because I think the situation it's so general that there should be a consolidated way to go.

Comment: This assumes there's at least 4 characters in the argument, so it'll crash on `.a`. Consider using `strrpos` to find the last `'.'`.

Comment: Note that `ext` is a pointer, so it won't be `<= 0` even if `strlen(argv[1]) - 4` *is* `<= 0`.

Comment: I missed the last strcpy, so yes, it will most likely crash, depending on the user input.#

Comment: The program assumes that the path separator character will be a backslash, so this is intended to be Windows-specific?

Comment: @user3386109 yes, my bad.. That test would've prevent the case of less than 4 char file names... Then should I check `ext-argv[1]`?

Comment: I would use `strrchr` to find the last `.` in `argv[1]` (if any). Then use `strcmp` to verify the `.foo` extension.

Comment: You're not allocating enough space for `out_name`.  You need to provide for a string terminator, too.

Comment: I would use `sprintf()` to write the output file name into the allocated space.

Comment: Sorry, I was testing the code and missed the fact that in the `"Non a .foo file"` check there should be a `return` statement.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I've increased the allocated length by 1, should I use `calloc` instead of `malloc`? And how about `sprintf()`?

Comment: The main difference between `calloc()` and `malloc()` is that the former zero-fills the allocated space.  That's wasteful if you're going to overwrite the whole thing anyway.

Comment: @JohnBollinger yes, I didn't know sprintf adds the trailing `\0`. Now I've changed it, thanks!

Comment: My point about `sprintf` was not that it is to be preferred over `strcpy`, but rather that *one* `sprintf` is better than *two* `strcpy`s.

Comment: @JohnBollinger How can I use _one_ `sprintf`?

Comment: Like this: `sprintf(out_file, "%.*s.bar", (int) (ext - basename), basename);`

Comment: Or like this: `sprintf(out_file, "%.*s%s", (int) (ext - basename), basename, ".bar"); `

Comment: @JohnBollinger Wonderful, I didn't know the existence of these options. Thanks again